# Having problem to import a module from different directory in python

Tags: python-3.x

[Image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTdtq.png) I have created **init**.py file in every folder

```
import Pages.login_page.LoginPage
```

```
>error:
>Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "D:\work\testAutomation\pythonEvaly\Tests\base_test.py", line 5, in ><module>
>    import Pages.login_page.LoginPage
>ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pages'
```

Comment: Please post text instead of images - see [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before importing we should append the parent directory

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".."))

#should import after above lines

from some_folder.some_file import some_module
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>The import would look like:</s>

```py
from ..Pages.login_page import LoginPage
```

The double dots mean that it will look for a module named Pages in the parent directory of the script.

Note:

```
This will only work if you have a __init__.py in the Pages folder
```

#### Edit

This should work...

```py
import sys

sys.path.append('../Pages')


import login_page.LoginPage
import home_page.HomePage
```

Comment: after adding two dots, from ..Pages.login_page import LoginPage
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package